# python use each line in for pool probleme

Tags: python, file

i'm programming a script that fetch the http response and searching for 200 responses 
i need to make url like this : 
http://exemple.com/string+number
like : http://exemple.com/hello123
        hello string is in sites.txt and some other strings ,   and i want to check them all with this 3 case numbers from 100 to 999 and this is the code : 
ok i will explain the code :) import urllib2

```
import string
#declaring the range of my pool
    def my_range(start, end, step):
        while start <= end:
            yield start
            start += step

    # open the file that contains the strings
    s = open("sites.txt","r+")
    # effect a value for url 
    url = 'http://exemple.com/'
    # initialize y to 100 cause i only need string+(100,999)
    y = 100
    # for pool to read the lines line by line
    for line in s.readlines():
    #initialize the y variable so it wont keep increasing by 1
     y = 100
     # effecting the line value to site so i can use it in the 2nd for pool
     site = line
     for x in my_range(100, 999, 1):
      url+=str(site)
      #increasing y by 1 to explore all the range (100,900)
      y =y+1
      #url = url+site+y like http://exemple.com/hello123
      url+=str(y)
      #checking wich url i reach it 
      print url 
      #all this to get a 200 response 
      req = urllib2.Request(url)
      try:
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
      except urllib2.URLError, e:
        if e.code == 404:
            pass
        else:
            pass
      else:
        print "200"
        #initializing the url so it wont going like this http://exemple.com/hello123hello123hello123
      url = 'http://exemple.com/'
    body = resp.read()
```

the problem the script get only the first string in the txt file and the file is by lines like this 
string1
string2
string3
string4
...
i'm a beginner with python so some explanation or rewrite on the code could be very helpful thanks for any help guys :)

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in `range`?

Comment: Perhaps you should sleep, and try asking [better questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) tomorrow?

Comment: there is no probleme in it i just can't use each line in my text file only the first string :/

Comment: Bad code, trashed indentation, unclear question. You can't change the first point (that's why you ask), but can you change the others?

Answer (score 2):

You make multiple requests and get a response from each, but you only `read` from the last one, because that is outside the loop.

Comment: thanks for your answer bro , how to do it exactly ? :)

Comment: I would start by thinking. If you understand even 10% of the code you have already shown us, it should be obvious to you how to proceed with this guidance.